# How to display 'loading' while loading PF chart

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have implemented PrimeFaces [chart](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/barChart.jsf) with SQL queries.

I noticed a performance problem while I open the JSF page with the chart. I'm interested is it possible to display "Loading.." at the center of the chart while the chart is ready for displaying?

***EDIT***

I added this insight of the chart div layer:

```
<div id="powerchart" style="position: absolute; left: 420px; top: 40px; width: 700px; height: 330px" rendered="#{not DCProfileTabGeneralController.editable}">
    <!-- Live update
    <p:poll interval="3" update="dcpower" />
    -->

    <p:ajaxStatus onstart="statusDialog.show();" onsuccess="statusDialog.hide();"/>

    <p:dialog modal="true" widgetVar="statusDialog" header="Status"
              draggable="false" closable="false">

    </p:dialog>

    <p:barChart id="dcpower" value="#{DCProfileTabGeneralController.dcPower}" rendered="#{not DCProfileTabGeneralController.editable}"
                title="Datacenter Power Usage Statistics" min="0" style="height:330px; top: 10px;"
                shadow="true" barMargin="50" seriesColors="F8F8F8, 888888, 005CE6, 0047B2" extender="dcchartConfig"
                yaxisLabel="Size" zoom="true" stacked="false" >
        <p:ajax event="itemSelect" listener="#{DCProfileTabGeneralController.itemSelectDCPower}" update="growl" rendered="#{not DCProfileTabGeneralController.editable}"/>
    </p:barChart>

</div>
```

But I noticed that when I click on the chart the entire JSF page displays message. How I can only display the message only insight the div layer? Is it possible?

Comment: use http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajaxStatus.jsf for all you ajax loadings...

Comment: Yes, I fond a possible solution. But is it possible to display loading only into the chart div instead of displaying it on the entire page?

Comment: well you could add some custom jquery code for example : insert animated image into chart div onstart and hide it oncomplete , onstart : `$('#dcpower').prepend('<img id="theImg" src="theImg.png" />')` oncomplete : `$("#theImg").hide();` <---- something like this

Comment: I don't need to display image. I only need "Loading...". Would you write your proposal as answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could experiment with [`BlockUI`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/blockUI.jsf) and the `preRenderComponent` event for the chart.

1. Add the event to the chart. You can use the event listener to initialize your chart

   ```
      <p:barChart id="dcpower" value="#{DCProfileTabGeneralController.dcPower}" rendered="#{not DCProfileTabGeneralController.editable}"
           title="Datacenter Power Usage Statistics" min="0" style="height:330px; top: 10px;"
           shadow="true" barMargin="50" seriesColors="F8F8F8, 888888, 005CE6, 0047B2" extender="dcchartConfig"
           yaxisLabel="Size" zoom="true" stacked="false" >
         <f:event id="chartBlocker" type="preRenderComponent" listener="#{DCProfileTabGeneralController.initChart}"/>
         <p:ajax event="itemSelect" listener="#{DCProfileTabGeneralController.itemSelectDCPower}" update="growl" rendered="#{not DCProfileTabGeneralController.editable}"/>
      </p:barChart>
   ```
2. Define a `<p:blockUI/>` outside the target panel

   ```
      <p:blockUI block="powerchart" trigger="chartBlocker" />
   ```

I haven't tested this but I believe the theory of it is plausible. If the event doesn't trigger the blockUI, try using the chart itself in the `trigger` attribute of blockUI

Answer (score 1):

Well you could add some custom jquery code for example : insert animated image into chart div onstart and hide it oncomplete ,

onstart : `$('#dcpower').prepend('<img id="theImg" src="theImg.png" />')`

oncomplete : `$("#theImg").hide();` <---- something like this

Or add some text like this

onstart : `$('#dcpower').prepend('<span id="theText">Loading...</span>')`

oncomplete : `$("#theText").hide();` <---- something like this