# How to display "Loading.." while loading div

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a JSF page with charts without AJAX support. I noticed that the time of loading of the charts is very slow. Is it possible for example to load the body of the JSF page and to display "Loading..." inside the DIVs where the charts are positioned while the chart is being loaded? I use Primefaces for charts generation.

Comment: Probably best idea is to do it with a lazy data loading enabled component, like `<p:tabView>` or `p:accordionPanel`. Not sure what you asking for can't really be done, because event `blockUI` has a client side API which you can call when page loads, I'm not sure how to call it for specific charts to stop. If charts are loading very slowly it will result in bad user experience, even you want to show all of them at the same time. *Divide et impera*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could experiment with BlockUI and the preRenderComponent event for the chart.  Refer this link [How to display 'loading' while loading PF chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14655048/how-to-display-loading-while-loading-pf-chart)

Answer (score 1):

you can use this prime-faces ajax code while you are trying to load

```
<p:ajax event="page" update=":statusbar"  onstart="statusDialog.show();" oncomplete="statusDialog.hide();" onerror="statusDialog.hide();"/>
```

from ajax you are calling to this dialog box

```
    <p:dialog widgetVar="statusDialog" id="statusbar" modal="true" showHeader="false" closable="false" width="250" resizable="false">
          <h:form>
//You can also give loading image here
            <div class="ft-row ft-center"><img src="#{request.contextPath}/resources/images/loding.gif" /></div>
            <h5>Please wait..</h5>
          </h:form>
        </p:dialog>
```